# Android OpenCV samples blank screen in Optimus black (GB)

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

Hello I'm new in the world on Android and OpenCV. I have some 
knowledge about Computer Vision (so little ).

I couldn't post all the links correctly so please remove the space after "http:"

Well, I followed the tutorial here: 
http: //opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

and manage to run the samples and get a functional menu but the screen is blank (all the samples actually run except the 
ones form native that crashed instantly).

I even compiled the latest source without any change.

I tried to run the apks included on the package OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin.tar.bz2 
refered on the mentioned tutorial. But it was no change. Even the 
"Tutorial 1 Basic 0 Android Camera " didn't run.

Also I tried this fix (it's for ICS but I thought it could help) without success: 
https: //groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/5ZKgvWBDtMU

I have installed some other apps based on OpenCV and worked fine 
one is ViewerCV ( https: //market.android.com/details?id=com.viewercv&hl=en ) 
and this ( https: //market.android.com/details?id=com.theveganrobot.cvcamera&feature=also_installed 
).

So it's possible to run OpenCV based apps on the device. I need help. 
I would like to code and Optical Flow app for a mobile robot and made 
the vision system Android and OpenCV based.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Technical data:

Optimus Black p970h
Android version: LG 2.3.4 (V20a)

Logcat for Tutorial 0 : http://www.box.com/s/52dy42dv0cdjxzol8gxl

Answer (score 2):

Well finally managed to run a sample (with native code), so in theory any sample can be modified in order to work with this device (I suspect of the OMAP platform). Following this instructions : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-opencv/KVqUzyF8e3A

and modified some things in order to show the Canvas the app just ran.

Greetings.